# Sending string to port via pySerial went wrong

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I'm beginning in Arduino programming, and I'm having some trouble with the write() command from pySerial library.
I have a arduino programm that works fine using the arduino IDE's Serial terminal. 
I can write commands and it returns me some text and change a camera's parameters using the blackmagic 3g-SDI shell. 
Everytime something is sent, it should return me a confirmation message or an error message, which proves me nothing is sent with pySerial write() function.
I also know there is an actual communication, because I can see the 'begin' message at the beginning of the programm when I use readline().

I have already tried using putty, and doing it directly in command lines following a complete tutorial step by step, but the same occure, I don't really know what more I can do, I'have visited way to many forums and topics and tried different stuff.

```py
import serial 
import time

arduino = serial.Serial("COM3",baudrate = 9600, timeout = 2)
#arduino.open()
print(arduino.is_open)
time.sleep(2)

def sendCommand(command):

    arduino.write(bytes(b"command"))
    done = arduino.readline()
    doneDecoded = done.decode('ascii')
    print(doneDecoded)
    print(done)
    print('done')

    pass



while True:
    command =input(" Write your command : ")
    sendCommand(command)
```

I expect any kind of response to my input from the arduino, but right now the response is just blank, as if he didn't receive any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely Arduino is just waiting for the EOL (end of line) character (or sequence) to start processing your variable length command.

The EOL usually is `\r` or `\n` or combination of both. Try sending that after your `arduino.write(bytes(b"command"))`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your sendCommand function sends the string "command" every time you call it, as such you have never sent any command to the Arduino which it would respond to.

Secondly, Your python code is working on your computer, which is probably clocked at 1.2 to 2.8 GHz, while the Arduino runs at a clock speed of 16 MHz, (That's almost 100 times slower)

When you send a command to the Arduino, you need to give the Arduino time to process the command and respond to it. I suggest adding a delay of about 100 milliseconds between the serial write and serial read as follows

```
def sendCommand(command):

    arduino.write(bytes(command))
    time.sleep(100)
    done = arduino.readline()
```

That should do the trick for you.